Why Doesn't Hibernate support full outer join?
I'm building a complex query where I need FULL JOIN... but the Criteria API only supports JoinType.LEFT, JoinType.RIGHT and JoinType.INNER. Why doesn't Hibernate support full outer join? Is there a workaround?
